# Number of permutations of the letters of the word SECTION which satisfy the stated conditions

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, permutations

I would like to check if all my answers are correct. Thanks.

> Find the number of ways in which the letters of the word SECTION can be arranged if
>
> **(i)** the letters are not in alphabetical order,
>
> **(ii)** the consonants (S, C, T, N) and vowels (E, I, O) must alternate,
>
> **(iii)** all the vowels are together,
>
> **(iv)** all the vowels are separated,
>
> **(v)** there must be exactly two letters between the two letters E and O

Answers:

(i) $~7! = 5040$

(ii) $~ 3! \cdot 4! = 144$

(iii) $~ \displaystyle {5 \choose 1} \cdot 4! \cdot 3! = 720$

(iv) $~ \displaystyle {5 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 4! = 1440$

(v) $~ \displaystyle {4 \choose 1} \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 3! = 96~$
$~~~($group E _ _ O, then slot into the $4$ spaces$)$

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you explained your reasoning rather than just writing down a formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, as letters are not in alphabetical order, the answer should be ($7! - 1$), as one of the arrangements has all letters in alphabetical order.

Second, third and fourth are correct. For the fifth question, leaving $E$ and $O$ aside, there are $5$ letters. We choose two letters to be placed between $E$ and $O$ using ${5 \choose 2}$. We can then arrange two letters in $2$ ways and we can arrange $E$ and $O$ in $2$ ways too. Finally we permute remaining $3$ letters and block of $4$ letters with $E$ and $O$ at two ends in $4!$ ways. So the answer should be,

$ \displaystyle {5 \choose 2} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4! = 960$.

Comment: Alternatively, for the last question, there are two ways to choose whether E appears before O or O appears before E, four positions in which the first of those two letters could appear, and $5!$ ways to arrange the remaining five letters in the remaining five positions, giving $2 \cdot 4 \cdot 5! = 960$ possible arrangements.